# Pass iterable as method argument?

Tags: java, methods, hash, arguments, iterable

I'm trying to use a third party library that has a method signature like so:

```
testMethod(Iterable<HashMap<String,Date>>, String, String)
```

**How can I pass an iterable to this method?**

I wanted to do something like the following, but it fails:

```
HashMap<String,Date> items = new HashMap<String, Date>();
items.put("item1", new Date());
items.put("item2", new Date());

testMethod(items, "more", "data");
```

Comment: @DaveNewton The target method is expecting `Iterable<HashMap<String,Date>>`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Oh, oops; in my head it was just a list of value types. It must be contagious.

Comment: @DaveNewton Bad case of the mondays, man!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ROFL. haha :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass an [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) or one of its subtypes, e.g., `List`, `Set`, etc. So, you can add the `HashMap` to a `List`, and pass it:

```
HashMap<String,Date> items = new HashMap<String, Date>();
items.put("item1", new Date());
items.put("item2", new Date());

List<HashMap<String, Date>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Date>>();
list.add(items);

testMethod(list, "more", "data");
```

Note that since the parameter type is `Iterable<HashMap<String, Date>>`, you can only pass - `List<HashMap...>` or `Set<HashMap...>`, etc. You cannot pass a `List<Map..>` in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your Map with some object which is Iterable. Using `Arrays.asList(T... a)` ought to work here.

```
HashMap<String,Date> items = new HashMap<String, Date>();
items.put("item1", new Date());
items.put("item2", new Date());

testMethod(Arrays.asList(list), "more", "data");`
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass an Iterable to the method. It looks like HashMap does not implement the [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface. You could either subclass Map and add the Iterable interface to your subclass, or pass in a list of your map's entries.